# Typescript - Not able to access the custom method in subclass

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript. I have sub classed Error and implemented a new method getCode() in MyError class.

```
export class MyError extends Error {
public code: number;
    constructor(code: number, message?: string) {
        super(message);
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, MyError);
        this.name = 'MyError';

        this.code = code;
    }
    public getCode() {
        return 405;
    }
}
let r: MyError = new MyError(404, "test");
console.log(r.getCode());
```

When I created an object of MyError class and try to access r.getCode() method, I get the below error.
Cant we add custom methods in a sub class. I didnt understand the reason why it was not able to find the function getCode()?

```
console.log(r.getCode());
TypeError: r.getCode is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\test\vscode-ws\MyError.js:35:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Something else is the issue. maybe didn't compile correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran into an issue specific to extending the Error class ( see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work).

As a workaround, adjust the prototype right after invoking `super()`:

`Object.setPrototypeOf(this, MyError.prototype);`